# Cannot store the image in MySql

Tags: mysql, blob

Here is my table,

```
create table image(
 name varchar(5) not null,
 icon blob not null 
);
```

and here is how I tried to insert the image,

```
insert into image values('Sent', load_file('F:/verified.gif'));
```

when I tried to execute insert query, it returns null saying,

```
Error Code: 1048. Column 'icon' cannot be null
```

no doubts about location of the image. I can guarantee.I am using **MySql 5.7**
The problem is This worked fine with the Mysql 5.1.
What have I missed here?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `INSERT INTO image(name, icon) SELECT 'Sent', load_file('F:\verified.gif')` Your path looks like windows so it should be `F:\verified.gif`

Comment: Consider it your lucky day. Stackoverflow is littered with so many explainations as to why you shouldn't save files as blobs. Just save the path

Comment: I tried your query @lad2025. but it doesn't work :(. any way thanks both of you.